# Enabling Mass Storage instead of MTP/PTP

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rom, usb-mass-storage

Is there any way to enable the old ***Mass Storage Mode*** in Android 4.4.2? Right now I can only see MTP or PTP modes, but not the Mass Storage mode that was used to be around in old versions(2.3, I guess).

The old Mass Storage Mode allowed me to play audio in my car when connected via USB, but ever since with the MTP, my music player doesn't recognize my device. Also when connected to PC, it enabled me to modify partitions directly.

Any ROM hacks or tweaks probably?

P.S. I have a rooted At&T Galaxy Note 2(Android 4.4.2)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Android has switched to the newer MTP/PTP protocols, so no, regular "mass storage mode" can't be enabled. (That is unless there's a ROM hack I haven't found.)

Source: [A post from 2013 confirming it's not a thing anymore](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=48394656&postcount=9).

Answer (score 0):

I can say it's possible because I have a **Tornado 348 Play** in which you have the **"USB Storage"** option enabled, in addition to the other options:

- Built-in CR-ROM
- Media device (MTP)
- Camera(PTP)
- Charge only

**P.S**: This response should be a comment, but the 50 points reputation didn't allow me to post it as a comment. :)